# Using Typescript functions in plain VueJS project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

TL;DR: How can I import and use a typescript module into my plain js Vue-Components?

I have a Vue 2 (not yet 3) project. In this project I've moved some logic to es modules for better testability and to make them more reusable. Something like this:

```js
export const getHistory = () => {
   // ...
}
```

In a plain JS Vue-Component I would then `import {getHistory} from '../modules/listHistory'` that function and use it in combination with some presentation logic.

Now, I would like to move this function to a typescript module like this:

```
interface ListHistory {
    id: number;
}

export function getHistory(): ListHistory[] {
  // ...
}
```

I (naively) assumed I could just continue importing the function and use it in the same way as before in my JS-Components. However, that doesn't work and fails with this error message:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ../../modules/listHistory in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/quick-actions/quick-actions.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

Following [the vue guidelines on typescript](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) I've added a `tsconfig.json` file to my project:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I've also added `typescript` as a dev dependency to my project.

While searching around for a solution I could only find people trying to import plain-js modules in typescript projects, nothing like the thing I want to do.

I know that importing Typescript stuff into plain JS code doesn't give you all the advantages of Typescript but since I will migrate the whole thing to VueJS 3 at some point and I do want to use types, I better start now by moving stuff that can already be moved to typescript.

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI ?

Comment: @MichalLevý Yes, Vue CLI.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-typescript

Comment: That seems to work great, thanks! Do you want to write a "real" answer to get the reputation or should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing TS and adding `tsconfig.json` config file to a Vue project based on Vue CLI/Webpack is not enough as you also need to configure Webpack to correctly handle TS files or `<script lang='ts'>` blocks in Vue SFCs (using [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader))

Easiest way to start using TS in a project managed by Vue CLI is using the CLI plugin [@vue/cli-plugin-typescript](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/typescript.html)

```
vue add typescript
```